# Fast HashCode of a Complex Object Graph

Tags: c#, .net, performance, hash-code-uniqueness

I have a pretty **complex object** and I need to get **uniqueness** of these objects. One solution can be done by overriding `GetHashCode()`. I have implemented a code noted below:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this._complexObject1.GetHashCode() ^
           this._complexObject2.GetHashCode() ^
           this._complexObject3.GetHashCode() ^
           this._complexObject4.GetHashCode() ^
           this._complexObject5.GetHashCode() ^
           this._complexObject6.GetHashCode() ^
           this._complexObject7.GetHashCode() ^
           this._complexObject8.GetHashCode();
}
```

These complex objects also *overrides* `GetHashCode()` and does *similar operations*.

*My project* requires uniqueness of these objects which I deal with these very **frequently**, and data inside also **changes** in **various ways and places**.

*I need a faster way to find uniqueness of these complex objects, which need to consider **performance** and **memory**.*

*Thanks in advance

Munim*

Comment: If the data is changing, `GetHashCode()` is probably the wrong thing to start with - besides, it can only guarantee non-equality (it **cannot** be used to test for equality).

Comment: Thanks Marc, I am not performing to test equality I use `GetHashCode()` to check the objects are not equal, and this is what I need to do

Comment: Just wanted to check. I'm not sure there is a magic-wand answer, though. You might be able to do something by caching the value and dropping the cached value when change happens, but that is tricky in a complex graph (as you need to check all the subobjects).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given your comment, it sounds like you may be trying to rely on GetHashCode *on its own* to determine uniqueness. Don't do that. Hashes aren't *meant* to be unique - it's meant to be *unlikely* that two unequal objects will hash to the same value, but not impossible. If you're trying to check that a set of objects has no duplicates, you will *have* to use Equals as well.

Note that using XOR for a hashcode can make it more likely that you'll get hash collisions, depending on the individual hash values involved. In particular, it makes any two equal fields "cancel each other out". I generally use this form:

```
int hash = 17;
hash = hash * 31 + field1.GetHashCode();
hash = hash * 31 + field2.GetHashCode();
hash = hash * 31 + field3.GetHashCode();
hash = hash * 31 + field4.GetHashCode();
...
return hash;
```

... but even so, that's certainly not going to guarantee uniqueness. You should use `GetHashCode()` to rule *out* equality, and then use `Equals` to check the actual equality of any potentially equal values.

Now your question mentions speed - this sounds like the perfect place to use a profiler and some benchmark tests. Are you sure this is a bottleneck? If you have many different types all computing hash values, have you found out which of these is the biggest contributor to the problem?

Some optimisations will depend on exactly how you use the data. If you find that a lot of your time is spent recomputing hashes for values which you know haven't changed, you could cache the hash code... although this obviously becomes trickier when there are fields which themselves refer to complex objects. It's possible that you could cache "leaf node" hashes, particularly if those leaf nodes don't change often (but their usage could vary).